# Android cursor sometimes returns empty even when the data exists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, cursor, is-empty

I have an android application that first fetch some data from the web (any updates that might available for an Item) and write the data and after that read the fetched data from the database.
The problem is in some cases the reading operation with android cursor returns an empty cursor but we know that the data exist because you updated that exact row some seconds ago!

In fact you can't request an online update for some data that not exist.  I searched a lot but no result. I thought I might be from reading and writing at the same time but It wasn't.

below is the code that do this work :

```
protected Biz doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bundle bundle = BizDetailsActivity.this.getIntent().getExtras();
            // bizID = bundle.getLong(BIZ);

            BizDataSource ds = new BizDataSource(BizDetailsActivity.this);
            ds.openWritable();
            long ID = bundle.getLong(BIZ);
            if (NetworkHelper.IsConnected(BizDetailsActivity.this)) {
                   // HERE we write data if avaiable
                    getBizOnline(ID, ds);
                }
                    //read data from database
                    biz = ds.getBiz(ID, data.getCurrentUser());
                    ds.close();
                        return biz;
}
```

Code for writing/updating data :

```
public long updateBiz(long ID, String title, String description,
            String address, String phone, String mobile, String fax,
            String owner, long city, String website, double latitude,
            double longitude, int addDate, String expireDate, long gallery,
            String logo, float rate) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(columns[1], title);
        values.put(columns[3], description);
        values.put(columns[4], address);
        values.put(columns[5], city);
        if (gallery > 0) {
            values.put(columns[6], gallery);
        }
        values.put(columns[7], latitude);
        values.put(columns[8], longitude);
        values.put(columns[9], phone);
        values.put(columns[10], mobile);
        values.put(columns[11], fax);
        values.put(columns[12], website);
        values.put(columns[13], owner);
        values.put(columns[14], logo);
        values.put(columns[15], addDate);
        values.put(columns[16], expireDate);
        values.put(columns[19], rate);

        long result;
        try {
            result = database.updateWithOnConflict("Bizes", values, "ID = ?",
                    new String[] { ID + "" },SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_FAIL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("UPDATE_BIZ", e.getMessage());
            result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Code for getting data :

```
public Biz getBiz(long id, long UserId) {
        Gallery gallery = null;
        City city = null;
        BizCategory category = null;
        Cursor c = database.query("Bizes", columns, "ID=?", new String[] { id + "" }, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst() == false) {
            // here we got empty cursor !!!!
            c.close();
            return null;
        } else {
....
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. My delete query was wrong and before getting data the was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code to read your cursor

```
            if(c != null){

             c.moveToFirst();

             while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

               c.moveToNext();                
             }

            }
```

Comment: Why? when I trace the code obviously the cursor contains no elements or row. The problem has nothing to do with the Cursor or reading method. I used same approach so many times in this application and all of them are correct

Comment: did you try to browse the database with device monitor and check if there is any actual data than?

Comment: I think the problem comes from a collision or something like that. because It's not happen every time and by reinstalling the application so the database the problem goes away ...

Comment: Do u think posting your dbhandler class could help?

Comment: I think I found the problem. every time I fetch the data I delete the old rows and It might come from removing wrong rows. because In fetch stage I only try to update the Data. I'll check and let you know. Thanks for the comments